# UnknownOperationException while sending WriteRecordsCommand to TimestreamWriteClient

Tags: aws-sdk-js

I'm developing a lambda function in AWS that pushes timeseries data to AWS TimeStream using the AWS SDK for Javascript `v3`. The code is very simple, but is not running:

```js
// Push the batch to timestream
await client.send(new WriteRecordsCommand({
    DatabaseName: config.datbase,
    TableName: config.table,
    Records: records
}));
```

the `records` is an array of object, containing the measurement name, value, and some dimensions:

```
{
  Time: "1614859498169",
  TimeUnit: "MILLISECONDS",
  MeasureName: "test",
  MeasureValue: "1",
  MeasureValueType: "DOUBLE",
  Version: 1,
  Dimensions: []
}
```

The AWS connection is perfectly valid, region set, ... But it results in the following error:

```
UnknownOperationException: UnknownOperationException

      24 | 
      25 |     // Push the batch to timestream
    > 26 |     await client.send(new WriteRecordsCommand({
         |     ^
      27 |         DatabaseName: config.datbase,
      28 |         TableName: config.table,
      29 |         Records: records

      at deserializeAws_json1_0WriteRecordsCommandError (../node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-timestream-write/protocols/Aws_json1_0.ts:1644:39)
      at ../node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-serde/src/deserializerMiddleware.ts:20:18
      at ../node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-signing/src/middleware.ts:26:22
      at StandardRetryStrategy.retry (../node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-timestream-write/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-retry/src/defaultStrategy.ts:125:38)
      at ../node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-logger/src/loggerMiddleware.ts:21:20
      at Object.publishMessages (publisher.ts:26:5)
      at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/publisher.spec.ts:17:9)
```

Which strategy should be followed to insert records into the timestream database?

Comment: I downgraded to the V2 SDK to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems SDK v3 is not resolving the endpoint automatically. You can try to get the AWS Timeseries endpoint before writing:

```
const getWriteClient = async () => {
  const { Endpoints } = await (new TimestreamWriteClient(timestreamConf))
    .send(new DescribeEndpointsCommand({}));
  return new TimestreamWriteClient({
    ...timestreamConf,
    endpoint: `https://${Endpoints?.[0].Address ?? `ingest-cell1.timestream.${timestreamConf.region}.amazonaws.com`}`,
  });
};
```

There is an open issue about this: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/1898